# How can I consolidate my code? JavaScript and PHP based issues

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, effects, modular

My page is rather simple and direct. I first call in external PHP pages as elements within my page using DIV tags. I then hide the div's that aren't needed on the home page and then slide into view the wanted "page" and hide the unwanted.

What I would like to do is slide in the wanted content and slide out what ever content is currently active/visible. I know I can just continue down the line what I've already begun doing but the entire document would be SO bloated. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
$(function(){
    $("div.design, div.marketing").hide();
    });
});

  $(document).ready(function() {

$("h3.home_button").click(function () {
      $("div.home").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
      $("div.design").hide();
      $("div.marketing").hide();
});

$("h3.design_button").click(function () {
      $("div.design").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
      $("div.home").hide();
      $("div.marketing").hide();
});

$("h3.marketing_button").click(function () {
      $("div.marketing").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
      $("div.home").hide();
      $("div.design").hide();
});


  });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="main">

    <div class="header">
        <?php include("header.php");?>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <?php include("menu.php");?>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <?php include("content_home.php");?>
        <?php include("content_design.php");?>
        <?php include("content_marketing.php");?>

    </div>
    <div class="footer"><?php include("footer.php");?></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `data attributes` and access it by the `data()` jquery method.

**in your HTML**

```
<h3 data-a='marketing'>marketing</h3>
<h3 data-a='design'>design</h3>
<div class='container'>
    <div style='display:none;' class='marketing'>
         marketing stuffs
    </div>
    <div class='design'>
         design stuffs
    </div>
</div>​
```

**and in your javascript**

```
$('h3').click(function(){
    type = $(this).data('a');

    $('.container div').hide();
    $('.container').find('.'+type).show();
})​
```

Here is an exemple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wzj3H/1/)

Also you are calling ready method twice